# A certificate verification problem was encountered while accessing postgresql in Stackbuilder

Tags: postgresql

When ever installing postgresql and trying to run stackbuilder there is a connection issue unable to connect and error message is "failed to connect to [www.postgresql.org](http://www.postgresql.org) port 443". I have tried both by using vpn and disconnecting from vpn.

Install postgis support on postgresql.

Comment: A network problem on your side.

Comment: I checked accesing the url via web browser but it works normally. Even it pops up with a error verifying certificate issue from https://www.postgresql.org/applications-v2.xml.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org currently uses a certificate signed by "Let's Encrypt" that is valid until Nov 15, 2023. Perhaps the web browser you are using does not recognize that certification authority. At any rate, not a programming problem.